# Query JSON inside MySql Column

Tags: mysql, xml, json

Is any way to query specific values from a JSON stored in varchar or string row in MySql? A little bit as using MongoDB (Or couch or raven) with out old friend MySql.

I know that even if I get to queries this values, I still will be missing all the features of NoSql solutions, but I just need to store schemaless information in MySQL.

PS: what if the data is stored as XML instead of JSON?

UPDATE: I want to add something for future reference:

**If you are looking for a way to have schemaless storage in a shared hosting, the easiest way is to sign up for a montodb hosted solution, or couchdb hosted solution (https://cloudant.com/#!/solutions/cloud for example).**

Comment: I bet there will be advices about looking at EAV, but personally I'd never recommend to even try to implement EAV in rdbms. If you want schemaless storage - get mongo ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot query JSON as 'JSON' within MySQL AFAIK. You can perform any operation which you can for that value as a 'varchar' but not as 'structured data in JSON format'. In other words, you can do 'like' or '=', but you will not be able to do something like `where x.y = 4`, or something like `order by x.z`, given the JSON structure of:

```
 {
    x: {
        y: 4,
        z: 10 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you storing XML/JSON data as one field in a database? If the structure contains more than one element, then you can break the data down into a smaller level of granularity.

Comment: He need schemaless way of storing. Schema-less doesn't fit relational dbms common schema.

Comment: Exactly. Also the problem is that is very difficult to use a NoSQL solution in a shared web hosting. I need the schemaless part, no the sharding, replication and scaling part :)