# SQL select Where Clause statement

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause

I am quite sure its not possible but I would like to ask the experts here  if its possible to  write a SQL statement to

```
Select * from ... Where [‘sent_to’]['bissness_id']=3516 .
```

If yes then what is the Syntax for it ? ( Please see the Picture below )

[image: Select * from ... Where sent_to['bissness_id']=3516]

Comment: Seems it duplicates http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5724845/query-json-inside-mysql-column

Comment: Why you are storing those `Bissness_id`'s in the same row for each query_id? Better off, create a new table `QueryBissnessss` with an entry for each id.

Comment: @MahmoudGamal - Yes , I know that is the way , but a person who was working before me created the structure in this way. So now the database has a huge data in this format so I wanted to Avoid changing the table structure.

Answer (score 1):

Something like this would work:

```
select * from web_query where sent_to like '%"business_ids":["3516"]%';
```

or, alternatively:

```
select * from web_query where sent_to like '%"business_ids":[%"3516"%]%';
```

But you really shouldn't be storing JSON as a string value in a database column. It kind of defeats the purpose of a database on several levels.

EDIT: if you'd like to avoid changing the table structure but would still like to benefit from structural improvements to the database layout, you could look into writing some views that would parse `sent_to` into view columns.

Comment: Another option would be to add a new table containing the linked business ids, but use a trigger to keep it populated. Also if you want a maintenance nightmare it would be possible to write a mysql function to check if a passed value is in the string, by breaking down the string within the function (I have done this for a php serialised array stored in a db field), but would advise against it.

Answer (score 0):

this should work:

```
select * from web_query where sent_to like '%"business_ids":["3516"]%';
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the below code

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_NAME t1
WHERE t1.sent_to.business_ids = 3516;
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have only businessIds on your sent_to column you could simply do:

```
Select * from ... Where sent_to LIKE '%"3516"%'
```

Answer (score 0):

i don' t think what u are asking can be done but what u can do this with simple trick

```
select * from yourtable where sent_to like '%5060%'
```

this will work getting u the rows with the business id 5060

u can choose to have separate table if u want more flexibility as per your requirement

Answer (score 0):

Not a very clear question..

If you have to cater for there being non "bissness_id" stuff in sent_to then you need to be explicit:

```
DECLARE @FilterID Varchar(10) = '"3516"'
Select * from ... Where sent_to LIKE '%'+@FilterID+'%'
                AND sent_to LIKE '%business_ids%'
```

If the column only has "bissness_id" then it's simpler

```
DECLARE @FilterID Varchar(10) = '"3516"'
Select * from ... Where sent_to LIKE '%'+@FilterID+'%'
```

Since in your example you have an integer on the where clause.. if this was intentional and part of the question then you can just use conversion:

```
DECLARE @FilterInt Int = 3516
DECLARE @FilterID Varchar(10) = '"' + CAST(3516 AS Varchar(10)) + '"'
Select * from ... Where sent_to LIKE '%'+@FilterID+'%'
                AND sent_to LIKE '%business_ids%'
```